# Persistence and mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-connection, g-wan

I'm trying to persit my mongoDB connection like that :

```
mongo **ptr = (mongo**)get_env(argv, US_VHOST_DATA);

if(!ptr[0]) {
  mongo_replica_set_init( conn, "cluster" );
  mongo_replica_set_add_seed( conn, "mongo1.mongood.com", 27017 );
  mongo_replica_set_add_seed( conn, "mongo3.mongood.com", 27017 );
  mongo_replica_set_add_seed( conn, "mongo4.mongood.com", 27017 );
  mongo_replica_set_add_seed( conn, "mongo5.mongood.com", 27017 );
  mongo_replica_set_add_seed( conn, "mongo6.mongood.com", 27017 );
  mongo_replica_set_client( conn );
  mongo_cmd_authenticate( conn, "dbname", "dbuser", "dbpass" );

  ptr[0] = (mongo*)calloc(1, sizeof(conn));
} else {
  conn[0] = *ptr[0];
}
int count = 0;
count = mongo_count( ptr[0], "dbname", "coll", NULL);

mongo_destroy( ptr[0] );

xbuf_xcat(reply, "<h3>%d</h3>", count);
```

But obviously, it don't work...
My goal is to avoid connection time on each request (~30ms)

It is doable ? What is wrong in this example ?

The code don't complain but it just return -1 instead of the right count number.

Thank you for your help.

---

[EDIT] Removing the else block and removing the mongo_destroy line just work as expected \o/

Comment: I suggest that you rather use a per thread connection by using the __thread keyword: **__thread conn** = 0; and then **if(!conn) { setup(); }** this way you will better use the MongoDB capabilities.

Comment: There is a sample somewhere?

Comment: Look at the mysql.c example provided with the G-WAN download. It does the same job in a way that will not confuse you

Answer (score 2):

I've never used mongo, but looking at your code you are allocating space to ptr[0] but you have not assigned anything to it, so subsequent calls will always return -1.
And the else block is doing nothing because you are making all mongo calls using ptr[0] instead of conn, so either remove the else block or correct all the mongo calls to use conn instead of ptr[0] and don't forget to assign conn to ptr after the calloc.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to said that I am not a C developer :) Trying to learn it actually

Comment: I just added ptr[0] = conn; below the calloc and removed else block ... but still -1 is returned
When calling script for the first time, it return the right number ...  then reloading provide a -1

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [mysql.c example](http://gwan.com/source/mysql.c) provided with the G-WAN download. It does the same job in a way that will not confuse you.